# Why can't a Bash script handle space and dash on Linux subsystem for Windows?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, filepath

I'm running a Linux subsystem on a Windows 10 machine. I wrote a script to download the latest build from a Jenkins server, renamed it, and saved it on the Onedrive mapped in Windows. The problem is those spaces and the dash in the path are not handled well when running the script.

The script is the one below:

```
#!/bin/bash
path=$(echo "OneDrive - Atos")
echo $path
echo "/mnt/c/Users/A474998/$xpath/"
filename=$(echo "\"/mnt/c/Users/A474998/$path/___Software/SIP_CP100.img\"")
echo $filename
curl http://jenkins.devices-dev.global-intra.net/view/mainline/job/we1_cp100_sip_arm_nightly/lastStableBuild/artifact/vobs/Opera_Build/Nightly/SIP/WP_LO_CP100/cruise/opera_bind.SIP.WP_LO.nand.img --output $filename
```

This is the output when I run the script

```
bokos@DESKTOP-DLETB9D:~$ ./testget
OneDrive - Atos
/mnt/c/Users/A474998//
"/mnt/c/Users/A474998/OneDrive - Atos/___Software/SIP_CP100.img"
curl: option -: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

[image: curl: option -: is unknown]

I run this script in debug mode and this is the output

```
bokos@DESKTOP-DLETB9D:~$ sh -x ./testget
+ echo OneDrive - Atos
+ path=OneDrive - Atos
+ echo OneDrive - Atos
OneDrive - Atos
+ echo /mnt/c/Users/A474998//
/mnt/c/Users/A474998//
+ echo "/mnt/c/Users/A474998/OneDrive - Atos/___Software/SIP_CP100.img"
+ filename="/mnt/c/Users/A474998/OneDrive - Atos/___Software/SIP_CP100.img"
+ echo "/mnt/c/Users/A474998/OneDrive - Atos/___Software/SIP_CP100.img"
"/mnt/c/Users/A474998/OneDrive - Atos/___Software/SIP_CP100.img"
+ curl http://jenkins.devices-dev.global-intra.net/view/mainline/job/we1_cp100_sip_arm_nightly/lastStableBuild/artifact/vobs/Opera_Build/Nightly/SIP/WP_LO_CP100/cruise/opera_bind.SIP.WP_LO.nand.img --output "/mnt/c/Users/A474998/OneDrive - Atos/___Software/SIP_CP100.img"
curl: option -: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

[image: fail in debug mode]

If I manually run the command from the debug mode I can download the file and save it in the correct Onedrive location

```
bokos@DESKTOP-DLETB9D:~$ curl http://jenkins.devices-dev.global-intra.net/view/mainline/job/we1_cp100_sip_arm_nightly/lastStableBuild/artifact/vobs/Opera_Build/Nightly/SIP/WP_LO_CP100/cruise/opera_bind.SIP.WP_LO.nand.img --output "/mnt/c/Users/A474998/OneDrive - Atos/___Software/SIP_CP100.img"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 22.2M  100 22.2M    0     0   747k      0  0:00:30  0:00:30 --:--:--  470k
```

[image: command produced from failing script working ok when executing manually]

I then copy this command in a script

```
#!/bin/bash
curl http://jenkins.devices-dev.global-intra.net/view/mainline/job/we1_cp100_sip_arm_nightly/lastStableBuild/artifact/vobs/Opera_Build/Nightly/SIP/WP_LO_CP100/cruise/opera_bind.SIP.WP_LO.nand.img --output "/mnt/c/Users/A474998/OneDrive - Atos/___Software/SIP_CP100.img"
```

and when I execute it, the file will be downloaded and saved in the correct location

```
bokos@DESKTOP-DLETB9D:~$ ./testget
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 22.2M  100 22.2M    0     0   790k      0  0:00:28  0:00:28 --:--:--  868k
```

[image: the same command copied in a script working ok]

I have tried lots of combinations with

```
" " ' ' ``
```

I cannot rename the path of Onedrive to remove space and dash.
So I m really confused and I don't know what I m doing wrong.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Double quote the variable: `curl http://jenkins.devices-dev.global-intra.net/view/mainline/job/we1_cp100_sip_arm_nightly/lastStableBuild/artifact/vobs/Opera_Build/Nightly/SIP/WP_LO_CP100/cruise/opera_bind.SIP.WP_LO.nand.img --output "$filename"`

Comment: hi @choroba
i have tried that 
This is the output
`bokos@DESKTOP-DLETB9D:~$ ./testget
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file "/mnt/c/Users/A474998/OneDrive -
Warning: Atos/___Software/SIP_CP100.img": No such file or directory
  0 22.2M    0  3529    0     0   5070      0  1:16:33 --:--:--  1:16:33  5063
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 3529)`

Comment: You do not have `"mnt` directory. You have `mnt` directory. So do not do `$(echo "\"` , just `filename="the string"`

Comment: GREAT..it worked now! Thank you both!